# JTable - UI freezes upon many insertions

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jtable, event-dispatch-thread

I have a GUI app which has a couple of tabs, each of which hosts one `JTable`. My UI class i processing events coming from the Controller in the following piece of code, which runs on EDT:

```
private void processAnalysisResult(AnalysisResult generatedValue) {
    LimitType limit = generatedValue.getMetric().getLimit();
    String limitName = limit.getName();
    int index = tabs.indexOfTab(limitName);
    Component component = tabs.getComponentAt(index);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = (JScrollPane) component;
    JTable table = (JTable) scrollPane.getViewport().getView();
    AnalysisResultTableModel model = (AnalysisResultTableModel) table.getModel();
    model.addRow(generatedValue);
    }
}
```

There are a couple of thousand newly generated results per second, atm I lowered it to about 10k. Even with that relatively low value the app freezes for about 10-20 secs processing the UI updates from Jtable. The `addRow` method calls `fireTableRowsInserted` mewthod upon insertion of each row, but can this be that slow?

EDIT: This is the code that processes the event (asynchronously called from the background processing thread):

```
  controller.addAnalysisGenerationListener(new GeneratedValueListener<AnalysisResult>() {
        @Override
        public void valueGenerated(final GeneratedValueEvent<AnalysisResult> event) {
            processEDT(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    processAnalysisResult(event.getGeneratedValue());
                }
            });
        }
    });


private void processEDT(Runnable runnable) {
    if (EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
        runnable.run();
    } else {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it can be that slow. 10k is not a low number. As you already noticed `addRow()` calls `fireTableRowsInserted()` which in turn notifies the view that a change happened and makes the view to be refreshed (but in this case the user doesn't see it because EDT is busy with processing the next results). 
One of solutions would be to execute `processAnalysisResult()` on background thread and update the model on EDT by passing the last line (`model.addRow(generatedValue);`) to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`. Maybe it will not be much faster but at least the GUI will not freeze for 20 seconds. 
Of course you can also use `SwingWorker` that is dedicated for such kind of tasks.
Additionally you can try to update the model in batches (eg. add every 100 results to the model on EDT at a time), which should minimize screen flickering.

Comment: SOrry, forgot to mention, the code that starts the whole analysis, that in turn calls the above method, is already running of the back of the background thread

Comment: If the GUI freezes it means that `processAnalysisResult()` is called in a loop on EDT in single event handling. The calling code should be changed so that `processAnalysisResult()` is called once per `generatedValue` on separate events sent to EDT. This way EDT will have a chance to process also other pending GUI events (ie. refresh the view). Another good idea is to extend the model by `addRows()` method that calls `fireTableRowsInserted()` once, as @StanislavL mentioned.

Comment: Well, what is going on is precisely what you described - the background thread is generating an event, which is subsequently processed, one at a time, on the EDT. But the GUI is still hanging...

Comment: Can you show the code that passes the events to EDT and calls `processAnalysisResult()` ?

Answer (score 4):

Guess the AnalysisResultTableModel is instanceof DefaultTableModel?

Try to add batch addRows() method instead of adding one by one.
addRow() calls the method

```
public void insertRow(int row, Vector rowData) {
    dataVector.insertElementAt(rowData, row);
    justifyRows(row, row+1);
    fireTableRowsInserted(row, row);
}
```

Try to implement something like this

```
public void insertRows(int row, Vector<Vector> rowsData) {
    for () {
        dataVector.insertElementAt(rowData, row);
        justifyRows(row, row+1);
    }

    fireTableRowsInserted(row, row+rowsData.size());
}
```